# Value column counts or Summarizes even if I checked "Dont Summarize" Power BI Desktop

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerquery

The goal is to create a visual that shows Budget vs Premium for each month in a year;
Something like that:

[image]

I established relationship between Premiums table and Divisions table. It didnt give me any error, so I'm assuming everything is fine.

[image]

On a chart I need SUM of premium but NOT SUM of Budget.
But when I put Budget on a column chart it summarizes it. I checked "Do not summarize" but it still, either summarize either count value.

Premium value summarized which is fine, that is what I need. But Budget value I do not need summarize or count.

[image]

Is it possible?
Why it acting that way?

.PIBX file is available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kvh7quylcirj0o/PremiumByDivisions1.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 6 `InsurType` and hence 6 `Budget` for each month.

That's why Power BI has to enforce a summarization to the `Budget` column when it's put in the `Value` of the chart.

---

To display `Premium` alongside `Budget` for each `InsurType`, you'll have to create a measure for each `InsurType` and add them to the chart:

e.g.

```
Commercial Auto Budget = 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Divisions 2'[Budget], 0),
    'Divisions 2'[InsurType] = "Commercial Auto"
)

Worker's Comp Budget = 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Divisions 2'[Budget], 0),
    'Divisions 2'[InsurType] = "Worker's Comp"
)

Specialty Casualty Budget = 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Divisions 2'[Budget], 0),
    'Divisions 2'[InsurType] = "Specialty Casualty"
)

...
```

You also have to change the `Cross filter direction` between `Premium` and `Division 2` table to `Both` so that the Date filter can be passed to the `Division 2` table.

Results:

[image: results]

P.S. If you're OK with not putting `Premium` in the same chart, then you can just create one measure for `Budget` and then put in `InsurType` as `Legend` to the chart to separate the types. (Legend is only usable when you have one `Value`)

Comment: Thanks. So how can I solve my problem? How can I proper display Premium vs Budget for each InsurType?

Comment: @Oleg Solutions updated. You'll have to create a measure for each `InsurType` and add them to the chart.