# Power BI - weighted average yield across 2 tables of a given date

Tags: powerbi

I would like to calculate average yield between two relation tables of a given date

```
Table1                               Table2
+-------------------------------+    +-------------------------------+
| ID     TradeDate       Amount |    | ID     TradeDate       Yield  |
+-------------------------------+    +-------------------------------+
| 1       2018/11/30      100   |    | 1       2018/11/8      2.2%   |
| 1       2018/11/8       101   |    | 1       2018/8/8       2.1%   |
| 1       2018/10/31      102   |    | 1       2018/5/8       2.0%   |
| 1       2018/9/30       103   |    | 2       2018/9/8       1.7%   |
| 2       2018/11/30      200   |    | 2       2018/6/8       1.6%   |
| 2       2018/10/31      203   |    | 2       2018/3/8       1.5%   |
| 2       2018/9/30       205   |    | 3       2018/10/20     1.7%   |
| 3       2018/11/30      300   |    | 3       2018/7/20      1.6%   |
| 3       2018/10/31      300   |    | 3       2018/4/20      1.6%   |
| 3       2018/9/30       300   |    +-------------------------------+
+-------------------------------+
```

I create a table named 'DateList' and use slicer to select a specified date.

Screen Shot DateList.
[image]

I want to achieve the following result:

```
as of *11/9/2018*
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID      LastDate       Value     LatestYieldDate     LastYield  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1       2018/11/8       101          2018/11/8         2.2%     |
| 2       2018/10/31      203          2018/9/8          1.7%     |
| 3       2018/10/31      300          2018/10/20        1.7%     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Total                   604                           1.7836%   |                   
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Currently, I use the following formula to achieve the partial result

Create 2 measures in table1

```
    LastDate = 
    VAR SlicerDate = MIN(DateList[Date])
    VAR MinDiff =
        MINX(FILTER(ALL(Table1),Table1[ID] IN VALUES(Table1[ID])),
            ABS(SlicerDate - Table1[TradeDate]))
    RETURN
        MINX(FILTER(ALL(Table1),Table1[ID] IN VALUES(Table1[ID])
            && ABS(SlicerDate - Table1[TradeDate]) = MinDiff),
            Table1[TradeDate])

    Value = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Amount]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[TradeDate] = [LastDate]))
```

Create 2 measures in table2

```
LastYieldDate = 
VAR SlicerDate = MIN(DateList[Date])
VAR MinDiff =
    MINX(FILTER(ALL(Table2),Table2[ID] IN VALUES(Table2[ID])),
        ABS(SlicerDate - Table2[TradeDate]))
RETURN
    MINX(FILTER(ALL(Table2),Table2[ID] IN VALUES(Table2[ID])
         && ABS(SlicerDate - Table2[TradeDate]) = MinDiff),
        Table2[TradeDate])

LastYield = CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[Yield]), FILTER(Table2, 
            Table2[TradeDate] = [LastYieldDate]))
```

I have no idea to calculate right average yield between 2 tables
Here is my current result.

Screen Shot Current Result.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to create a bridge table for the `ID` values so you can work with both tables more easily.

```
IDList = VALUES(Table1[ID])
```

[image: Bridge Table]

Now we'll use `IDList[ID]` on our visual instead of the `ID` from one of the other tables.

The measure we use for the average last yield is a basic sum-product average:

```
LastYieldAvg = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(IDList, [Value] * [LastYield]),
    SUMX(IDList, [Value])
)
```

Note that when there is only a single `ID` value, it simplifies to

```
[Value] * [LastYield] / [Value] = [LastYield]
```

[image: Result Table]

Comment: Thanks again Alexis. Can i use DAX directly rather than to create a bridge table?

Comment: Hi Alexis, if i have additional column named [company] (such as A, B, C,...) in table 1 & table 2, how can i combine [company] & [ID] in bridge table [IDList]? Thanks

Comment: There are some [workarounds for creating relationships on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852514/how-to-join-tables-on-multiple-columns-in-power-bi-desktop).